# Database tuning performance from play framework in play scala project

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.2, mysql-error-1064, slick

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsJDBC talks about some additional tuning performance params, but did not say anything about suggestions/advices on best or moderate settings.

Wonder if anyone has any suggestions/advice on these Additional Tuning Performance parameters?

Also, I have the following SQL error alot. Wonder if it is something to do with the tuning settings as I have all stable builds such as bonecp 0.8.0.RELEASE, play 2.2.2, play Slick 0.6.0.1 etc.

```
Caught SQLException!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after  connection closed.
```

Would really appreciate any response on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception's message you want to apply a db operation (whatever create, select, update or delete this may be) on an already closed connection. Could you past some code?

btw: I'm running bonecp 0.8.0 as well and I'm not experiencing these exceptions with using this (development) config:

```
db {
  default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:postgresql://.../database"
  default.user=some-user
  default.password="some-pass"
  default.logStatements=true
  default.maxConnectionAge=0
  default.logStatements=true
  default.maxConnectionAge=0
  default.partitionCount=1
  default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=10
  default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
}
```

Maybe you can try to tweak your config settings when inspecting the "BoneCpPlugin": "https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/879588fd9d1b1cdeb800f904a454014e51a8568e/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/BoneCPModule.scala"

Comment: That is right. But I didnt close the connection myself. Play Slick handles it for me. All that I have done is wrap my code in    "Database() withTransaction { implicit session => //any operation like insert/read etc" which I think Slick would handles accordingly.

Comment: Might be useful going through this thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1243551

Comment: I see you point... but again, I'm not experienceing these issues. If(!?) I remember correctly I had some kind of "connection closing" issue about a year ago with BoneCP 0.7.x as well. Not sure that was solved in a newer version or it was the setting "maxConnectionAge=0".

Comment: Yup, this specifically (default.maxConnectionAge=0) is what my previous thread suggested as well. Let me give it a try. Btw, it happens only on production though (not locally)

Comment: But yes, it is likely (atleast for you) that the setting default.maxConnectionAge=0 fix the issue rather than the bonecp version being either 0.8.0-RELEASE or 0.8.0-snapshot version.

Comment: Somehow I cannot find play versions above 2.2.3 suffering from these issue. I´m running 2.3.6 since yesterday, before 2.3.1 for about 6 months. How about updating play framework? here's also a discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/7PBnjiXkNuU

Comment: What if default.maxConnectionAge=0 hampers performance? It would be a bad approach setting that to zero if we want some performant interaction with database (by reusing the existing the connection rather than closing it each time the connection is done). Any thoughts?

Comment: Agreed that sounds like a performance bottleneck. I'll test that with our application as well.

Comment: @zochhuana @tfh there is no bottleneck with `maxConnectionAge=0`, a zero value means never forcibly close connections. See here: https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp/src/main/resources/bonecp-default-config.xml#L66

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add "db.default.maxConnectionAge=0" code in applications.conf file. This one line code is enough.

Comment: Hi Bala, please refer to the comments of the first answer. Your suggested setting might resolve this problem but there is the negative side of it as well.